# Response is improper when sending HttpWebRequest using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm having a problem when sending HttpWebRequest to a particular url.
The response is generated but it is not that I want.
It is giving a response like "Session Timeout! Please Login to continue".
Whereas,
When I'm sending the same request through Python 3.4 it is giving me the required response.
The response is like "--some html is here--" which I want.

I don't know why this is happening because I wan't it to do throught C#.

The CodeBehind (giving the wrong response) is:

```
    string postData = "somequerystring";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("someurl");
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36";
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
    using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string responseFromServer = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();     
    response.Close(); 
    Context.Response.Write(responseFromServer);
```

The Python Script (giving the correct response) is:

```
import requests
url = "someurl"
payload = "somequerystring"
headers = {
'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Help me out?

Comment: Are you sure they are equivalent? Isnt python sending the data as part of the querystring, whereas the C# program is sending it as part of the POST payload?

Comment: both of them are POST requests!
the c# code is making a request, generating response and exists(that is happening I guess) that is why it outputs "Session Timeout"

Comment: Yeah I know both are POST requests. There are two ways to send a post. One way is to urlencode your parameters and send them as part of the request body. The other is to encode them in the URI itself. I think python might be encoding it in the uri, not the body like your C# code.

Comment: So how to urlencode in c# .. any idea?

Comment: Use WebClient.UploadValues()

Comment: 'using (WebClient client = new WebClient())

        {

            byte[] response =

            client.UploadValues("someurl", new NameValueCollection()

            {

           { "txtInst", "Institute" }, 
        ,
           { "Password", "ddssd" },
           { "BTNSubmit", "Submit" }
            });
            
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            Context.Response.Write(result);
        }

its the same result as the previous one "Session Timeout! Please Login to continue".'

Comment: It probably needs cookie container to be initialized. You will need to write your own webclient inheriting from System.net.WebCLient. Then, get  a  handle to HttpWebRequest object and set a cookie container on it. Then try